# Excel : Use data in one table of Excel to calculate values in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a simple food nutrient calculator on excel that I can share with others.

I have one sheet with list of food items and nutrient information per 100 grams:

| Item | Weight (g) | Calories | Protein | Carbs | Fat | Fiber | Sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rice White | 100 | 130 | 2.7 | 28 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| Rice Brown | 100 | 111 | 2.6 | 23 | 0.9 | 1.8 | 0.4 |
| Almonds | 100 | 579 | 21.15 | 21.55 | 49.33 | 12.5 | 4.35 |
| Peanuts | 100 | 567 | 25.8 | 16.13 | 49.24 | 8.5 | 4.72 |
| Cashew | 100 | 553 | 18.22 | 30.19 | 43.85 | 3.3 | 5.91 |
| Walnuts | 100 | 654 | 15.23 | 13.71 | 65.21 | 6.7 | 2.61 |
| Pistachios | 100 | 560 | 20.16 | 45.32 | 27.17 | 10.16 | 7.66 |
| Hazelnuts | 100 | 628 | 14.95 | 16.7 | 60.75 | 9.7 | 4.34 |
| Rice Basmati | 100 | 121 | 3.54 | 25.22 | 0.38 | 0.4 | 0.05 |

I want another sheet where the user logs amount of each food item he or she consumes for the day. I want the item names to be from the drop-down . Rest of the columns need to be calculated.

| Time | Item | Amount (g) | Calories | Protein | Carbs | Fat | Fiber | Sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 AM | (item name dropdown) | 200 | (formula) | (formula) | (formula) | (formula) | (formula) | (formula) |

Can you explain how to achieve this?

I can create the a list from the Item Name column in the sheet1 using Data Validation, but how to get the rest of the column values from Sheet1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that source data is in `A1:H10` and then second table data is in `K1:S2` then in cell `N2` i.e. for Calories formula would be:

`=INDEX($C$2:$H$10,MATCH($L2,$A$2:$A$10,0),MATCH(N$1,$C$1:$H$1,0))*($M2/INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH($L2,$A$2:$A$10,0)))`

where

`=INDEX($C$2:$H$10,MATCH($L2,$A$2:$A$10,0),MATCH(N$1,$C$1:$H$1,0))` matches values from calories table and then multiplier is calculated by dividing the total quantity by reference amount in column B using `$M2/INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH($L2,$A$2:$A$10,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Format as table. (Select table > Home > Format as Table)
2. Give a name. (Table > Table Name). I chose "FoodTable".
3. On the new sheet create the table with headers. I added a few more to make it easy to debug the formulas:

| Time | Item | Weight (g) | Reference Weight | Calories Original | Protein Original | Carbs Original | Fat Original | Fiber Original | Sugar Original | Calories | Protein | Carbs | Fat | Fiber | Sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 AM | Rice Brown | 200 | 100 | 121 | 3.54 | 25.22 | 0.38 | 0.4 | 0.05 | 242 | 7.08 | 50.44 | 0.76 | 0.8 | 0.1 |

4. Add data validation to Item column (Data > Data Validation > Validation Criteria > Allow > List. You can choose the source to highlight the item column)
5. In the Reference Weight column you can enter the following formula to find Weight in FoodTable: `=INDEX(FoodTable[Weight (g)],MATCH([@Item],FoodTable[Item]))`
6. Repeat the same for other "Original" Columns.
7. Fill in the Calories with the formula: `=[@[Weight (g)]]*[@[Calories Original]]/[@[Reference Weight]]`. Repeat for other columns.
8. Optionally, hide the "Original" columns.